# Can we extract delta data from RestAPi through Azure DataFactory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My Source is Rest API (comma separated value format)..how can I extract delta data in Azure Data factory?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be to copy the data from the REST API to a staging table in Azure SQL and then set up incremental copy from the staging table to your final sink dataset.

Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview

Hope this helps.